# Why do we copy 0x0 to Stack pointer Register?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, att, objdump

I have a small source file m.c

```
extern void a(char *);

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    static char string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    a(string);
}
```

`a` is an external function. When i dump the disassembly of above code, it emits the below output :

```
m.o:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <main>:
extern void a(char *);

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
    static char string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    a(string);
   9:   c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
  10:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   11 <main+0x11>
}
  15:   c9                      leave
  16:   c3                      ret
```

I have two Questions :

1. Since there is a static variable holding the string, why i dont see `.data` section in this disassembly code.
2. what is the purpose of this instruction : `movl   $0x0,(%esp)`. Why are we zero-ing the stack pointer before call to `a` ?

Comment: That immediate is subject to relocation, filled in by the linker.  Instead of disassembling object files, I recommend you to instruct the compiler to generate assembly files with the `-S` option.

Comment: read-only constant data goes in `.rodata`.  And 2: you're looking at an unlinked `.o` with a placeholder and relocation, but you forgot to use `objdump -dr` to show it.  Also, `(%esp)` is a memory destination.  It's pushing it, not writing the the `%esp` register.

Comment: This does not zero out `esp`, it writes zero (which is later relocated as other mentioned) onto the stack, because it's an argument to the function. `sub esp; mov [esp]` is essentially a push.

Comment: [objdump and resolving linkage of local function calls?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8992938) is a duplicate for why it's `0`.  There's probably another duplicate somewhere else about how to read AT&T addressing modes with the difference between `%esp` and `(%esp)`.

Comment: For a good look machine code generated by the compiler, linker, and loader (operating system) consider using a debugger on a running program.  Otherwise you have to understand a lot about different kinds of metadata that is all telling the linker & loader what to do to prepare the program to run.  When debugging the running program you can see the *final results* of the efforts of translation into machine code.  You can also single step to see what it's doing!

Comment: the address for the local global "string" is not determined until link time and also at that time the linker will fill that address in where the 0 placeholder sits for the final binary.

Comment: You may find the output of `gcc -S -O m.c` easier to understand.  This produces a file of assembly language, instead of the "object file" you're trying to disassemble; it will include everything that went into the object file, so for instance the static variable will be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not putting 0 int `esp`. It's putting what looks like a 0 into where `esp` points to. This is the first argument to function `a`. At link time, the 0 will be replaced with the address of the string array `main::string` which must be placed in the data area because it's writable.

Comment: `main::string` -- this isn't C++, you know. it's just "the local variable `string`".

Comment: @JL2210: Sorry. I needed some notation for it.

Comment: Any idea why there is no .data area , since local static variable string is defined ?

Comment: @AbhishekSagar There is a `.data` section.  The command you used to get the disassembly dump (`objdump -d`, unless I miss my guess) only shows the contents of the `.text` section.  You can see a list of all the sections in the object file with `objdump -h` and you can see the contents of the data section with `objdump -s -j .data`.